# How to fail a constructor with new(std::nothrow)?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, new-operator, nothrow

Consider the following code:

```
#include <new>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void * operator new(size_t size) {
    void *res;
    if (size == 1) {
        res = NULL;
    } else {
        res = malloc(size);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "%s(%zu) = %p\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, size, res);
    if (res == NULL) throw std::bad_alloc();
    return res;
}

void * operator new(size_t size, const std::nothrow_t&) {
    void *res;
    if (size == 1) {
        res = NULL;
    } else {
        res = malloc(size);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "%s(%zu) = %p\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, size, res);
    return res;
}

void operator delete(void *ptr) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s(%p)\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ptr);
    free(ptr);
}

void operator delete(void *ptr, const std::nothrow_t&) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s(%p)\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ptr);
    free(ptr);
}

class Foo { };

class Bar {
public:
    Bar() : ptr(new Foo()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: ptr = %p\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ptr);
    }
    Bar(const std::nothrow_t&) noexcept : ptr(new(std::nothrow) Foo()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: ptr = %p\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ptr);
    }
    ~Bar() noexcept {
        delete ptr;
    }
    Foo *ptr;
};

class Baz {
public:
    Baz() : ptr(new Foo()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: ptr = %p\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ptr);
    }
    ~Baz() {
        delete ptr;
    }
    Foo *ptr;
};

int main() {
    Bar *bar = new(std::nothrow) Bar(std::nothrow_t());
    if (bar != NULL) {
        delete bar;
    } else { fprintf(stderr, "bad alloc on Bar(std::nothrow_t())\n"); }
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    try {
        bar = new(std::nothrow) Bar();
        delete bar;
    } catch (std::bad_alloc) { fprintf(stderr, "bad alloc on Bar()\n"); }
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    try {
        Baz *baz = new Baz();
        delete baz;
    } catch (std::bad_alloc) { fprintf(stderr, "bad alloc on Baz()\n"); }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
void* operator new(size_t, const std::nothrow_t&)(8) = 0x1fed010
void* operator new(size_t, const std::nothrow_t&)(1) = (nil)
Bar::Bar(const std::nothrow_t&): ptr = (nil)
void operator delete(void*)((nil))
void operator delete(void*)(0x1fed010)

void* operator new(size_t, const std::nothrow_t&)(8) = 0x1fed010
void* operator new(std::size_t)(1) = (nil)
void operator delete(void*, const std::nothrow_t&)(0x1fed010)
bad alloc on Bar()

void* operator new(std::size_t)(8) = 0x1fed010
void* operator new(std::size_t)(1) = (nil)
void operator delete(void*)(0x1fed010)
bad alloc on Baz()
```

As you can see allocating the first Bar succeeds despite the allocation of Foo failing. The second allocation of Bar and alloaction of Baz fail properly through the use of std::bad_alloc.

Now my question is: How to make "new(std::nothrow) Bar(std::nothrow_t());" free the memory for Bar and return NULL when Foo fails to allocate? Is dependency inversion the only solution?

Comment: Does the syntax have to be `new(std::nothrow) Bar(std::nothrow_t());`?  How about `Bar::create( std::nothrow_t{} )`?  Or `create<Bar>( std::nothrow_t{} )`?

Comment: Do you mean class Bar { public: static Bar * create(); private: Bar(Foo *foo); }? That would be using dependency inversion.

Comment: No, `Bar` can still create the `Foo`.  You'd just detect failure in your creator function and deallocate & return null.  The details are less important than the fact that we aren't doing it with `new` anymore, and this might not be acceptable to you.

Comment: Ok. slightly different from full dependency inversion. But for this to work in a general manner classes need an is_good() method, one has to check that after the constructor and the destructors have to handle badly initialized classes. I was hoping to still benefit from the automatic cleanup you have with exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose you want to be able to have failed construction without exceptions as a general rule.

I will sketch such a system.

```
template<class Sig>
struct has_creator;
template<class T, class...Args>
struct has_creator<T(Args...)>
```

this is a traits class that descendes from `true_type` iff your type `T` has a static method that matches the signature `bool T::emplace_create(T*, Args&&...)`.

`emplace_create` returns false on creation failure.  The `T*` must point to an uninitialized chunk of memory with proper alignment and `sizeof(T)` or larger.

We can now write this:

```
template<class T, class...Args>
T* create( Args&&... args )
```

which is a function that detects if `T` `has_creator`, and if so allocates memory, does an `emplace_create`, and if it fails it cleans up the memory and returns `nullptr`.  Naturally it uses nothrow `new`.

You now use `create<T>` in place of `new` everywhere.

The big downside is that we don't support inheritance very well.  And composition gets tricky: we basically write our constructor in `emplace_create` and have our actual constructor do next to nothing, and in `emplace_create` we handle failure cases (like sub objects having a failed `create<X>` call).

We also get next to no help with inheritance.  If we want help with inheritance, we can write two different methods -- one for a no-failure initial construction, and the second for failure-prone creation of resources.

I will note that it gets a touch less annoying if you stop storing raw pointers anywhere.  If you store things in `std::unique_ptr` everywhere (even to the point of having `create<T>` returning `std::unique_ptr<T>`), and throw in a guarded end-of-scope destroyer with abort, and your destructor has to be able to handle "half-constructed" objects.

Comment: This sounds like a more fancy way of using factory functions. I will have to see how that looks with full code compared to simple factory functions. FYI: The note about unique_ptr is gold. I see that I haven't looked into the new C++11 features enough. Thanks.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow honestly, it probably looks really ugly: this is just me spitballing a solution in an attempt to do away with exceptions but give exception-like mechanics.

Answer (score 2):

C++11 §5.3.4/18:

> **”** If any part of the object initialization described above terminates by throwing an exception and a suitable
>   deallocation function can be found, the deallocation function is called to free the memory in which the object
>   was being constructed, after which the exception continues to propagate in the context of the *new-expression*.

So `std::nothrow` does not guarantee no exception from a *new-expression*. It’s just an argument passed to the allocation function, selecting the no-throwing one from the standard library. It’s apparently mainly in support of more C-style pre-standard code.

The whole cleanup mechanism in modern C++ is based on exceptions.

To work around that – which I think is silly, not a thing to do, but you’re asking – do e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <stdlib.h>         // EXIT_FAILURE
#include <typeinfo>
#include <utility>

namespace my { class Foo; }

template< class Type, class... Args >
auto null_or_new( Args&&... args )
    -> Type*
{
    #ifdef NULLIT
        if( typeid( Type ) == typeid( my::Foo ) ) { return nullptr; }
    #endif

    try
    {
        return new( std::nothrow ) Type( std::forward<Args>( args )... );
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
}

namespace my
{
    using namespace std;

    class Foo {};

    class Bah
    {
    private:
        Foo*    p_;

    public:
        Bah()
            : p_( null_or_new<Foo>() )
        {
            clog << "Bah::<init>() reports: p_ = " << p_ << endl;
            if( !p_ ) { throw std::runtime_error( "Bah::<init>()" ); }
        }
    };
}  // namespace my

auto main() -> int
{
    using namespace std;
    try
    {
        auto p = null_or_new<my::Bah>();
        cout << p << endl;
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch( exception const& x )
    {
        cerr << "!" << x.what() << endl;
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

---

Why the requested approach IMHO is silly:

- It forsakes the safety of exceptions. No guaranteed cleanup on failure propagation. Indeed no guaranteed failure propagation, it’s all very manual.
- It discards all information about the failure, e.g. exception message. One can add mechanisms to retain some of that, but it gets complicated and inefficient.
- It has no plausible advantage that I can think of.

---

In passing, note that format specifier `%zu` and macro `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` don’t work with Visual C++.

Also note that in order to return a nullpointer, an allocation function must be declared to be non-throwing.

---

**Addendum**

An example of doing things very very manually, avoiding even internal exceptions. Mainly the cost is that one gives up the usual C++ machinery where only those data members already successfully constructed, are destroyed when failure is detected. Instead everything must be constructed to dummy states, so that one has **zombie objects** temporarily available.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <stdlib.h>         // EXIT_FAILURE
#include <typeinfo>
#include <utility>

namespace my { class Foo; }

struct Result_code { enum Enum { success, failure }; };

template< class Type, class... Args >
auto null_or_new( Args&&... args )
    -> Type*
{
    #ifdef NULLIT
        if( typeid( Type ) == typeid( my::Foo ) ) { return nullptr; }
    #endif

    auto code = Result_code::Enum();
    auto const p = new( std::nothrow ) Type( code, std::forward<Args>( args )... );
    if( p != nullptr && code != Result_code::success )
    {
        p->Type::~Type();
        ::operator delete( p, std::nothrow );
        return nullptr;
    }
    return p;
}

namespace my
{
    using namespace std;

    class Foo { public: Foo( Result_code::Enum& ) {} };

    class Bah
    {
    private:
        Foo*    p_;

    public:
        Bah( Result_code::Enum& code )
            : p_( null_or_new<Foo>() )
        {
            clog << "Bah::<init>() reports: p_ = " << p_ << endl;
            if( !p_ ) { code = Result_code::failure; }
        }
    };
}  // namespace my

auto main() -> int
{
    using namespace std;
    try
    {
        auto p = null_or_new<my::Bah>();
        cout << p << endl;
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch( exception const& x )
    {
        cerr << "!" << x.what() << endl;
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: The code is ment to work without exceptions because it has to be usable in contexts where exceptions are not available. But your code throws a std::runtime_error. It might as well throw std::bad_alloc and do it "right[tm]" then. The goal is to return a NULL pointer when Bar can't be fully created.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow In that case, you are pretty much doomed. A constructor cannot return anything in C++, so you must either use a factory method of one form or another, or you must move the construction code into a separate `init()` function. This really is one of the design flaws in C++, if you ask me.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: Without throwing you have no good way to back out of a constructor. Allocating all needed resources before constructing, and passing in those resources, gets rather ugly. But you can pass a boolean or enum by reference so that the constructor can indicate failure back up to a factory function.